# Error:Cannot destructure property 'tags' of 'this.state' as it is undefined.Actually this.state.tags exists

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[image]

Actually, "tags" exists.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-tag-input-1nelrc

I tried the above code.

It seems that state.tags is defined.

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      user: this.props.user,
      tags: [],
      suggestions: suggestions,
    };
    this.handleDelete = this.tagHandleDelete.bind(this);
    this.handleAddition = this.tagHandleAddition.bind(this);
    this.handleDrag = this.tagHandleDrag.bind(this);
    this.handleTagClick = this.tagHandleTagClick.bind(this);
  }


  tagHandleDelete(i) {
    const { tags } = this.state;
    this.setState({
      tags: tags.filter((tag, index) => index !== i),
    });
  }

  tagHandleAddition = (tag) => {
    this.setState((state) => ({ tags: [...state.tags, tag] }));
  }
```

Comment: this.tagHandleDelete= this.tagHandleDelete.bind(this);

Comment: Your stackblitz code is working fine. There is no error.